# Get current logged in user's user role from a laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

In my laravel application I have two user tyoes, admins and general users.

I have implemented function for users to download their certificates.

For that I got following function inside my controller

```
public function index(string $locale, CertificateUser $certificateUser)
    {
        
        $this->authorize('downloadCertificate', [Institute::class, $certificateUser, $institute]);

        try {
            return Storage::download($certificateUser->certificate_url);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException $exception) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(__('Certificate could not be found.'));
        }
    }
```

now I want to execute this

```
$this->authorize('downloadCertificate', [Institute::class, $certificateUser, $institute]);
```

only if the logged in user's user role is an admin...

How can I get the current logged in User's user role from here?

Comment: do you store user role info in 'users' table ?

Comment: Auth::user() and auth()->user(), both of this will return loggedin users instance

Comment: yes users are stored in the user table

Comment: try dd(Auth::user()) and check what you get

Answer (score 0):

```
if(auth()->user()->role=="Admin"){
//do something
}
```

it works well on my code

Answer (score -1):

```
>  $user_role = Auth::user()->role;
>  if($user_role  == 'admin'){
>  // You code Here
> $this->authorize('downloadCertificate', [Institute::class, $certificateUser, $institute]); } What's the issue ?
```

.Also Share you
User Model Here

Other Ways ....

```
 if($user->hasRole->name('Admin'))
 $user_roles = Auth::user()->roles()->get();
```

Now You can loop through $user_roles ..

Comment: your other way gives me an error saying undefined method called roles, and the first one giving me an array

Comment: $user = Auth::user() ; if($user->hasRole('admin'))

Comment: undefined method hasRole